# Bucle para sacar gráficos

Tags: r

Tengo estos datos:

```
    structure(list(Municipio = c("Territorio1", "Territorio1", "Territorio1", 
                                 "Territorio1", "Territorio1", "Territorio1", "Territorio1", "Territorio1", 
                                 "Territorio1", "Territorio1", "Territorio1", "Territorio1", "Territorio1", 
                                 "Territorio1", "Territorio1", "Territorio1", "Territorio1", "Territorio1", 
                                 "Territorio1", "Territorio1", "Territorio1", "Territorio2", "Territorio2", 
                                 "Territorio2", "Territorio2", "Territorio2", "Territorio2", "Territorio2", 
                                 "Territorio2", "Territorio2", "Territorio2", "Territorio2", "Territorio2", 
                                 "Territorio2", "Territorio2", "Territorio2", "Territorio2", "Territorio2", 
                                 "Territorio2", "Territorio2", "Territorio2", "Territorio2", "Territorio3", 
                                 "Territorio3", "Territorio3", "Territorio3", "Territorio3", "Territorio3", 
                                 "Territorio3", "Territorio3", "Territorio3", "Territorio3", "Territorio3", 
                                 "Territorio3", "Territorio3", "Territorio3", "Territorio3", "Territorio3", 
                                 "Territorio3", "Territorio3", "Territorio3", "Territorio3", "Territorio3"
    ), 
Año = c(2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 
               2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 
               2020, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 
               2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 
               2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 
               2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020), 

    Población = c(1958, 1968, 1981, 1970, 1982, 1993, 2010, 
                  2060, 2124, 2124, 2181, 2165, 2165, 2166, 2149, 2114, 2073, 
                  2047, 2026, 2020, 2035, 2014, 2030, 2009, 1984, 1974, 1937, 
                  1890, 1887, 1891, 1894, 1863, 1859, 1858, 1843, 1832, 1820, 
                  1811, 1781, 1746, 1723, 1706, 1820, 1840, 1833, 2029, 2157, 
                  2231, 2351, 2586, 2798, 2881, 2898, 2971, 2987, 3084, 3089, 
                  3110, 3135, 3137, 3193, 3197, 3201)), row.names = c(NA, -63L
                  ), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))-> datos
```

Quiero hacer un bucle que me saque un gráfico por territorio:

```
unique(datos$Municipio)-> titulo


for(i in 1:3) {
  
  titulo[i]->titulo2
  nombre=paste0(titulo2,".png")
  png(filename = nombre, width = 800, height = 600)
  
  datos[datos$Municipio==titulo2,]-> df1
  min(df1$Población)-> min
  max(df1$Población)-> max
  
  
  ggplot(df1, aes(x = Año, y = Población)) +
    geom_line()+labs(title = titulo2)+
    theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))+
    scale_y_continuous(limits = c(min, max+(max*0.02)))
  
  
  dev.off()
}
```

Pero no sale nada.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo único que le faltaría a tu código es invocar explícitamente un `print` del gráfico:

```
  ggplot(df1, aes(x = Año, y = Población)) +
    geom_line()+labs(title = titulo2)+
    theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))+
    scale_y_continuous(limits = c(min, max+(max*0.02))) -> gg
  
  print(gg)
```

De todas formas, te sugiero una forma más consistente con el universo `tidyverse`, particularmente hay un lote para generar el gráfico que incluye la configuración de las variables `max_val`  y `min_val` (Nota: no es bueno usar como nombre de variables el de una función) y por último usamos `ggsave()` con el gráfico recién generado.

```
library(tidyverse)

for(municipio_sel in unique(datos$Municipio)) {

  datos %>% 
    filter(Municipio == municipio_sel) %>% 
    { max_val <<- max(.$Población); min_val <<- min(.$Población); . } %>% 
    ggplot(mapping = aes(x = Año, y = Población)) +
      geom_line() +
      labs(title = municipio_sel) +
      theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
      scale_y_continuous(limits = c(min_val, max_val + (max_val*0.02))) -> gg
  
    ggsave(paste0(municipio_sel, ".png"), 
           plot = gg, 
           width = 800, 
           height = 600, 
           units = "px")

}
```

Nota: `ggsave()` es la forma oficial para guardar los gráficos de `ggplot()` pero no es compatible con el flujo normal de un lote `tidy` por lo que si o sí hay que ejecutarlo fuera del "batch".